# how can I use long polling to automatically refresh a webpage

Tags: ajax, cgi, long-polling

I am trying to figure out how to use long polling to trigger a webpage refresh (the entire page as opposed to just a single section). Although it would be nicer to just update part of the page instead of a single section, I would rather just get down the initial page refresh part and then move on from there. Having said that, I was wondering if anyone would be able to point me in the right direction as to how I can go about doing this? I have been searching for examples of long polling online, but unfortunately have not been able to find anything similar to this yet. Pretty much I would have a webpage which I could remotely refresh using long polling based on some condition on the server (apache on debian), so for instance if I had a bash script based cgi page that showed am or pm based on the server time, when the time on the server changes from am to pm or vice versa, the server would trigger a page refresh on the client side so the cgi page would reload and display the correct data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all. if you do long polling requests you need to keep in mind, that there will be an open connection to your server for each page that is viewed in the browsers.
That requires that your server infrastructure is able to handle this without huge memory consumption and wont run out of free connections to handle the long polling request.

i don't assume you use php but it is an good example: so if you have apache with php module, there is on the one hand a limit of maximum connection by configuration of apache and on the other hand for each connection the whole php module is loaded which uses much memory if you have many page views. if you use php-fpm as fcgi, there is also a maximum number of available clients, and you also don't want to increase this number over a certain limit.

so generally i would suggest not to use long polling request for public websites, if you don't have a good server backend that has some nice logic for handling this.

depending on the requirements you could think of the following solution, if you know in which intervals that page should check for refresh:

you could add a attribute `data-check-for-refresh-at` and `data-modified-at` to your html node:

```
<html data-check-for-refresh-at='2013-02-04 12:00:00 GMT' data-modified-at='2013-01-01 12:00:00 GMT'>
```

parse this with javascript and then do a refresh check at this time submitting the `modified-at` time with that request. if the content changed you will submit the new content, and the next time when the client should check for updates.

another thing that is important that you should add a random offset to this refresh time by the client, otherwise you probably DDOS yourself. because all clients would send a refresh request at the same time.

**EDIT (Based on comments)**

First a short explanation how it should be done for real system:

The server should not use one threads or processes per connection, instead it should use the event driven approach (registering callbacks to be informed if streams are ready to read or write). then if a long polling request arrives the server stores the information about which changes the client wants to be informed. then the connection is *sleeping* there are no cpu circles wasted for that connection anymore until client needs to be informed, also the memory usage is quite low. then if a url changed the server will be informed that is should notify all clients that listen to changes of this url. The server then will submit the responses to clients (a publication subscription system). depending on the number of clients to be notified the notifications should probably be queued and handled in an intelligent way, so that you would have a better balancing of the outgoing traffic. With this approach you will more likely run into the maximum allowed openports/filedescriptor problem then having problems with cpu or memory usage.

Of course this is a very simplistic description, but I think it is sufficient to get ene idea how it would be implemented.

**Quick&Dirty Solution**
It is more pseudo code then real code, so this would not work with copy and past, also it is assumed that the server creates the files for `$notificationFile` before any long polling request arrives):

The long polling request will call a php script like this:

```
set_time_limit(0);

/*
$urlToCheck and  $modificationTimeToCheckAgainst should be initialized by the values send by client as parameter for the long polling request
$someTime should be the maximum time the long polling request should be keept alive
*/
$forceResponseTimeout =  microtime(true) + $someTime;
$urlToCheck = "the/url/to/observe.html"; 
$modificationTimeToCheckAgainst = "2013-02-05 00:00:00"; //should be the time in seconds (not a real date)

$notificationFile = "./tmp/observer-file-".sha1($urlToCheck);

$responseStatus = "did-not-change";
while( microtime(true) < $forceResponseTimeout ) {
   clearstatcache(); //need to clear cache otherwise we don't have the right modification date (also not the beast idea to keep cpu usage low)
   if( filemtime(".update-check-file-".sha1($pathToCheck)) > $modificationTimeToCheckAgainst ) {
        $responseStatus = "changed";
        break;
   }
   usleep(100); //this is a bad idea because it creates a high cpu usage, even with the sleep
}

echo $responseStatus;  //here some json response should be created, the client then gets the information if it should resend the long polling request or if it should do a refresh.
```

The update script should look like this:

```
 $urlThatIsUpdated = "the/url/to/observe.html";

 //doing the update of the file


 $notificationFile = "./tmp/observer-file-".sha1($urlThatIsUpdated);

 touch($notificationFile); //updates the modification time of the notification file, which should be recognized by the script above.
```

Comment: hello, thanks for the info. This would not really be a public thing, more of just a prototype of something that I am doing for a project, so it would be "active" for maybe an hour or so while I am demonstrating it. the current server setup is apache2 (mpm-worker) with mod_fcgid & php5-cgi using varnish as a frontend (machine itself has 16GB of ram and a 100Mbps internet connection), do you think i would be able to handle a small implementation at least of long polling with that? also will check out the data-checked-for-refresh thing as well

Comment: im more or less just looking for a way to update the data in an instant manner (why long polling was appealing, had thought about a websocket, but that seems like overkill for this implementation)

Comment: @lacrosse1991 if it is just for a internal demonstration/proof-of-concept then i assume that you will just have one or two open windows. and for this you can use long polling requests. i was talking about 100+ clients showing the page at the same time. where you already could have about 0.5 GB memory usage for the long polling requests if you use apache + php_mod configuration. even with php5_cgi or php_fpm it would not be better.

Comment: ok thanks, could definitely see how a large amount of clients would take up a sizable amount of system resources. In that case, would you know how to go about doing the page refresh thing using long polling? Have been searching around for examples of such a thing, but unfortunately have not been able to find much of anything

Comment: @lacrosse1991 i can update my answer for an example for your case. but not until the next day. basically it will work the way, that in you long polling script you have a loop what checks every x second for an update of a file. you update script will do a touch to that file at the time the modification was done. and then you long polling script will send a response for refresh (but this is REALLY quick&dirty and not for production)

Comment: sounds good, an example would be very helpful, although in the meantime I will see if I can make a working implementation (will let you know I am able to in order to save you the work of making an example), not a problem with the quick and dirty implementation either, not a permanent solution or anything of the sort, more just for a demonstration of an idea (part of a project I have to do for a college course having to do with enterprise integration)

Comment: will be a webpage that displays data (fake item purchase data for instance) which can be altered via a web interface (most likely using cgi scripts, etc, nothing complicated), and then I will be using the long polling to keep results current across different machines, so when someone alters the data on one computer, anyone else who currently has the data open on their own computer will be able to see the updated results instantly